# How to save multiple inputs of rows in the same column of database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Database table

```
id  | title | reading | writing | speaking
```

form.blade.php

```
<table><tr>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th>Reading</th>
    <th>Writing</th>
    <th>Speaking</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="TitleText_1" id="TitleText_1"/></td>
    <td>
        <select name="ReadingText_1" id="ReadingText_1">
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="langWrittingText_1" id="WrittingText_1">
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="SpeakingText_1" id="SpeakingText_1">
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input name="TitleText_2" id="TitleText_2" /></td>
    <td>
        <select name="ReadingText_2" id="ReadingText_2">
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="WrittingText_2" id="WrittingText_2">
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="SpeakingText_2" id="SpeakingText_2">
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

LanguageController.php

```
   $languages = Language::create(array

   (

   'title' => $input['TitleText_1'],

   'reading' => $input['ReadingText_1'],

   'writting' => $input['WrittingText_1'],

   'speaking' => $input['SpeakingText_1'],
$languages->save();

  ));
```

I want what will be the controller code to save into the database. as there are multiple inputs of same label.

How to get all the inputs in controller? Also how to save multiple inputs into database of same column? I am a newbie of Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple inputs with same name like this

```
<input name="TitleText[]" />
<select name="ReadingText[]" >
...
<select name="langWrittingText[]">
...
<select name="SpeakingText[]">
...
```

This way the data will be posted in the form of an array.
Assuming that all the inputs/select are required to be filled by the user

In your controller you can do something like this

```
$count = count($input['TitleText']); // here we will know how many entries have been posted
$languages = array();
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
   if(!empty($input['TitleText'][$i])){
     array_push($languages, array( // iterate through each entry and create an array of inputs
      'title' => $input['TitleText'][$i], 
      'reading' => $input['ReadingText'][$i], 
      'writting' => $input['WrittingText'][$i],
      'speaking' => $input['SpeakingText'][$i]
     ));
   }
}
Languages::insert($languages); // save the array of models at once
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shows this error::
ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::saveMany()
@Dhiraj Bodhicherla

Comment: it works...but there is a problem i am facing that if one of the three label is filled it saves not only one i filled the label but also that i don't filled saving in the database with blank value and how to show only the filled value in the browser. plz help @Dhiraj Bodicherla..

Comment: are you talking about the `TitleText` ?

Comment: yes, if all are not filled then i want to show only the filled label and also save only the filled label into database. But now if i fill only one, it also saves the rest of the two labels with blank value and also shows blank value in the browser. how to solve this?

Comment: add an if condition. I updated my answer, please check

Comment: instead of `isset` try `!empty` like this `if(!empty($input['TitleText'][$i])){` or you could probably just use `if($input['TitleText'][$i]){`